# Reasonable way to use BitBucket deployment key and git push with ID

Tags: git, deployment, ssh, ssh-keys, ssh-agent

First, I use a deployment key for automated scripts which deploy environments. BitBucket does not count a deployment key (read only) towards a user limit. I realized with a little more configuration I can push directly with my user ID even though all other actions executed with the deployment key. This config allows me to promote readily with my user ID with virtually no effort. Is this approach reasonable or is there something inherently wrong with it?  Please take a look.

Here is the method that I used to configure the environment.

My repository is private and is owned by a BitBucket team not an account

Executed keygen twice on my workstation. First time create the deployment key:

`ssh-keygen -b 2048 -t rsa -f /tmp/depKey -q -N ""`

second time create the key for my user with `-f /tmp/myKey`. Added portion of *depKey* as deployment public key to a repository on BitBucket. Add other public key, myKey, to my account on BitBucket.

Then added the deployment private key
ssh-add ~/.ssh/deploy

checked with `ssh-add -l`

`2048 aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff:00:11:22:33:44:55:66:77:88:99 depKey(RSA)`

Bitbucket only accepts the first key managed by the SSH agent.

setup SSH config file as:

```
~/.ssh/config

StrictHostKeyChecking=no
Host myKey
      user myuser
      Hostname bitbucket.org
      IdentityFile ~/.ssh/myKey
      IdentitiesOnly yes
```

Create name *myKey* (actually a repository alias)

```
git remote add benKey git@benKey:appworksadmins/appworks.git
```

Example of what I do with this configuration. First checkout and pull performed with deployment key

```
git checkout master 
git pull origin master
git merge test
```

Pushed to the remote repository with

```
git push myKey master
```